# Repeatedly read input from external program vim

Tags: vim

I frequently do something like

`!r git diff .`

And I've simplified the refreshing of this input down to:

`:call feedkeys('ggdG:r! git diff .')`

but that still requires at minimum: `: <UP> <UP> <CR> <CR> <CR> gg` to repeat and move up to the first line for inspection.

How can I refresh the content with fewer steps? Bonus points for remembering the line one was on before refreshing.

I'm aware that there's [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) for the git specific commands, but I want to generalise it to running any shell command.

Comment: you want to read **output** from external program, not input, pls fix the title.

Comment: @Kent I was thinking out the output from some other application as input to Vim. Is it really less correct with the current title?

Comment: @Kent To put a different way, some other application writes output, but vim reads input. That sounds right at least in my head.

Comment: OK, I see your "output" from ext. cmd here is "input" for vim. fine. check the answers, if any of them helps.

Comment: I know you want a general solution, but please use fugitive for git commands. It really is quite nice. See: [The Fugitive Series - a retrospective](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2011/05/the-fugitive-series/)

Answer (score 3):

how about this mapping:

```
nnoremap <F10> :%d<bar>r! YOURCMD<cr>gg
```

then you can press `<F10>` to clear your current buffer and read output of `YOURCMD`, finally move cursor to the first line.

E.g. to load the processes information to vim:

```
nnoremap <F10> :%d<bar>r! ps -ef<cr>gg
```

Answer (score 3):

Steve Losh's [Clam](https://github.com/sjl/clam.vim/) is a generic and simple way to do what you do:

- show the output of an external command into a new vertical window

  ```
  :Clam git diff .
  ```
- refresh

  ```
  \r
  ```
- go to first line

  ```
  gg
  ```